# French and English text in one document with a single style of footnote

Tags: footnotes, hyphenation, babel

I have a book containing essays variously in English and French and wish hyphenization and other aesthetic issues to match whatever language is in use at the moment, but I want footnotes to follow a single style throughout. I've defined that style (hanging) using `footmisc` and have loaded `babel` with options `[english,french]`.

My problem is that when `babel` is fed the option `french`, footnotes appear in French style, indented rather than hanging; if I omit the option `french`, the footnotes come out hanging, but there are periodic hyphenization errors. Below I show my code without option `french` (I've included `geometry` and `\familydefault` options in order to reproduce a particular error):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.25in, bmargin=1.25in, lmargin=1.25in, rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{qtm}

\begin{document}

Il est possible de tirer quelques conclusions de ces r\'esultats. Il para\^itrait que l'\'eglise du milieu du XIIe si\`ecle comportait vraisemblablement un chevet plat, construit sur l'emplacement du mur Gallo-Romain qui a \'et\'e arrach\'e sur une longueur correspondant \`a la largeur de l'\'eglise actuelle.\footnote{Apr\`es tamisage, les ossements et les deux planches ont \'et\'e remis en place sous l'escalier. Ces deux cercueils en ch\^ene \`a clous forg\'es semblaient assez r\'ecents.}

\end{document}
```

Output (observe the herniated right margin of the text and the footnote's hanging style): [image: babel without french, text] [image: babel without french, footnote]

---

Here is the code with `french` included in `babel`'s input:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.25in, bmargin=1.25in, lmargin=1.25in, rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{qtm}

\begin{document}

Il est possible de tirer quelques conclusions de ces r\'esultats. Il para\^itrait que l'\'eglise du milieu du XIIe si\`ecle comportait vraisemblablement un chevet plat, construit sur l'emplacement du mur Gallo-Romain qui a \'et\'e arrach\'e sur une longueur correspondant \`a la largeur de l'\'eglise actuelle.\footnote{Apr\`es tamisage, les ossements et les deux planches ont \'et\'e remis en place sous l'escalier. Ces deux cercueils en ch\^ene \`a clous forg\'es semblaient assez r\'ecents.}

\end{document}
```

Output (observe the correctly justified right margin of the text and the footnote's indented style): [image: babel with french, text] [image: babel with french, footnote]

---

In addition, with `babel` set for English alone, I've tried setting the `hyphenrules` environment to `french` around the French essays, hoping to see only hyphenization follow French style and the footnotes be left alone, but no joy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a few changes your MWE is running. Change the line where you load `babel` (the change causes that you get the footnote style you want because english becommes the activ language)  and change always the language with `\selectlanguage{}`. This is neccecary too if you load a language as class option. Here is the changed MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.25in, bmargin=1.25in, lmargin=1.25in, rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{qtm}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
Il est possible de tirer quelques conclusions de ces r\'esultats. Il para\^itrait que l'\'eglise du milieu du XIIe si\`ecle comportait vraisemblablement un chevet plat, construit sur l'emplacement du mur Gallo-Romain qui a \'et\'e arrach\'e sur une longueur correspondant \`a la largeur de l'\'eglise actuelle.\footnote{Apr\`es tamisage, les ossements et les deux planches ont \'et\'e remis en place sous l'escalier. Ces deux cercueils en ch\^ene \`a clous forg\'es semblaient assez r\'ecents.}.

\clearpage
\selectlanguage{english}

Text in English\footnote{This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

With `texdoc babel` you can read on page 106:

> 29.1 Basic interface
>   In a multilingual document, some typographic rules are language dependent, i.e. spaces before
>   ‘double punctuation’ (: ; ! ?) in French, others concern the general
>   layout (i.e. layout of lists, footnotes, indentation of first
>   paragraphs of sections) and should apply to the whole document.
>
> Starting with version 2.2, frenchb behaves differently according to
>   babel’s main language defined as the last option25 at babel’s loading.
>   When French is not babel’s main language, frenchb no longer alters the
>   global layout of the document (even in parts where French is the
>   current language): the layout of lists, footnotes, indentation of
>   first paragraphs of sections are not customised by frenchb. When
>   French is loaded as the last option of babel, frenchb makes the
>   following changes to the global layout, both in French and in all
>   other languages

Comment: Hm! Quite interesting. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It is also interesting that placing `french` before `english` as an option to `babel` changes the situation.

Comment: It seems that `babel` activates the footnote style depending on the active language (the last one). So you can change afterwards the language with `\selectlanguage` for the right hyphenation ...

Comment: I never cease to boggle at the hidden complexities of this remarkable tool, TeX.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the following line after loading `babel`:

```
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}
```

`frenchb` has lots of options to modify its behaviour.