# footmisc hang and multiple only work with english document langage

Tags: lyx, footnotes, languages, footmisc

When I set the document to my local langage, French, and with appropriate quote style in LyX, this preamble doesn't work (neither hang nor multiple, which other options do work),

```
\usepackage[hang,multiple]{footmisc}
```

I could visualize the 'hang' behaviour correctly when switching back to English.  Same with 'multiple'.  I am glad to see that hang can even be cumulated with para -- it actually fixes the para layout!  Unfortunately none of them (and maybe other footmisc options aswell) do work in my configuration when setting up the language.

LyX 2.0.5.1
MiKTeX 2.9 up-to-date

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66162) answers your questions (TLDR: add `\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}` after loading `babel`). FYI, see the §29.15 (as the whole §29) of [`babel`'s documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/babel) as well as [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66139) on how the french option of babel redefines footnotes (among others).