# biblatex and footfullcite behaviour depending on babel option...?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, babel, footcite

I noticed a surprising behaviour of the `footfullcite` command while preparing a beamer presentation. My mwe contains two files (.tex and .bib), see below. If I compile the .tex file with the line

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

I get reference numbers that are not properly aligned with the reference text (more precisely, I would like to remove the *superscript* look of the reference number and add that I believe this way of numbering is **not normal** as when the number exceeds 99, it **overlaps with the reference text**).

[image: babel english]

However, if I use the option `french`:

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

then the numbers and the text are perfectly aligned: a beautiful harmony !

[image]

As you can see, I tried to force the language to `british` in the `biblatex` options... but it did not change anything.

One way around I found was to use the `otherlanguage` package and change the definition of my `\bib` command but this is not satisfying as my bibliographic references will be in French ! Is there any explanation on why `babel` options could impact the reference numbering ?

**tex file**:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[%
style=verbose,autocite=footnote,maxnames=1,firstinits=true,
babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,doi=true,
backend=bibtex,language=british]{biblatex}
 
\bibliography{zotero_bib}  
\newcommand{\bib}[1]{\phantom{\footfullcite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\frame[t]{
\frametitle{title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 1
        \begin{itemize}
            \item to be cited\footnotemark
            \item to be cited too\footnotemark
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
% citations 
\addtocounter{footnote}{0}\bib{black_interaction_2006}\bib{shaw_dynamic_2006}
}   
\end{document}
```

**bib file**:

```
@article{black_interaction_2006,
    title = {Interaction of a {Whirling} {Rotor} with a {Vibrating} {Stator} across a {Clearance} {Annulus}:},
    shorttitle = {Interaction of a {Whirling} {Rotor} with a {Vibrating} {Stator} across a {Clearance} {Annulus}},
    url = {https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1243/JMES_JOUR_1968_010_003_02},
    doi = {10.1243/JMES_JOUR_1968_010_003_02},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2020-03-10},
    journal = {Journal of Mechanical Engineering Science},
    author = {Black, H. F.},
    month = feb,
    year = {2006},
    note = {Publisher: SAGE PublicationsSage UK: London, England}
}

@article{shaw_dynamic_2006,
    title = {The {Dynamic} {Response} of {Tuned} {Impact} {Absorbers} for {Rotating} {Flexible} {Structures}},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {1555-1415},
    url = {https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/computationalnonlinear/article/1/1/13/464900/The-Dynamic-Response-of-Tuned-Impact-Absorbers-for},
    doi = {10.1115/1.1991872},
    language = {en},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2020-03-10},
    journal = {Journal of Computational and Nonlinear Dynamics},
    author = {Shaw, S. W. and Pierre, C.},
    month = jan,
    year = {2006},
    note = {Publisher: American Society of Mechanical Engineers Digital Collection},
    pages = {13--24}
}
```

Comment: For `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, what's not properly aligned? You mean the "indentation"? or the `superscript` look?

Comment: I mean the ```superscript``` look indeed

Comment: french has different typhographic conventions, also regarding footnote marks.

Comment: yes but is it normal to have a superscript look for references in English ? That looks odd to me. A normal bibliography does not look like that usually...

Comment: Your reference are simply footnote, and share their look with other footnotes. Why should footnotes with references be different? (I did not try to understand what the \phantom is supposed to do, and why you are adding zero to the footnote counter).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this mwe is extracted from a larger research presentation and I intend to have bibliographic references listed at the bottom of each slide, keeping a similar look to usual reference lists. The ```\addtocounter{footnote}{0}``` is required in the full presentation to make sure that the reference number at the bottom of the page is the same as the one on the slide.

Comment: Adding zero to a counter doesn't change it. \setcounter{footnote}{0} could have a sense but not \addtocounter.

Comment: This command allows to change the numbering of the references on each slide. Without it the counter would be incremented twice: one with ```\footnotemark``` and one with ```\bib```

Comment: My experience on this site has been that if people use a `verbose` citation style and/or `\footfullcite` in a `beamer` presentation they don't actually want what those concept. People are usually looking for something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45406/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543557/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biblatex follows the style for the language used by `babel`/`polyglossia` (and `csquotes`).

Footnote numbers are superscripts in english, british, danish, italian, ...

Why not use `\footfullcite` directly?

An experiment:

[image: french style]

Do you need to start with `1` on each slide?

The French style is more 'open', and easier on the eye, I find.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{lorenz,
author = {Katharina G Lorenz},
year = {2014},
title = {The Casa del Menandro in Pompeii},
subtitle ={Rhetoric and the Topology of Roman Wall Paintings},
pages={183-210},
editor = {J Elsner and M Meyer},
booktitle = {Art and Rhetoric in Roman Culture},
publisher = {Cambridge},}

@INCOLLECTION{auler:hiller:2011,
 AUTHOR = {Jost Auler AND Petra Hiller},
 TITLE = {Ein Kinderschuh des 19. Jahrhunderts aus Dor\-ma\-gen\--Stür\-zel\-berg, Rhein-Kreis Neuss},
 KEYWORDS = {Schuh, Kind, Dormagen, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 19. Jahrhundert},
 CROSSREF = {radmacher:kronsbein:2011},
 PAGES = {65--73},
 GENDER = {pp},
 SHORTTITLE = {Kinderschuh},
 GENDER = {pp},
}
@COLLECTION{radmacher:kronsbein:2011,
 EDITOR = {Franz-Josef Radmacher AND Stefan Kronsbein},
 TITLE = {Archiv und Erinnerung im Rhein-Kreis Neuss},
 TITLEADDON = {Festschrift für Karl Emsbach},
 FESTSCHRIFT = {Karl Emsbach},
 DATE = {2011},
 PUBLISHER = {Kreisheimatbund},
 SERIES = {Schriftenreihe des Kreisheimatbundes Neuss},
 NUMBER = {18},
 LOCATION = {Neuss},
 LANGUAGE = {german},
 GENDER = {pm},
 }

@book{cicero,
  author       = {Cicero, Marcus Tullius},
  title        = {De natura deorum. {\"U}ber das Wesen der G{\"o}tter},
  date         = 1995,
  editor       = {Blank-Sangmeister, Ursula},
  translator   = {Blank-Sangmeister, Ursula},
  afterword    = {Thraede, Klaus},
  language     = {langlatin and langgerman},
  publisher    = {Reclam},
  location     = {Stuttgart},
  langid       = {german},
  indextitle   = {De natura deorum},
  shorttitle   = {De natura deorum},
  annotation   = {A bilingual edition of Cicero's \emph{De natura deorum}, with
                  a German translation. Note the format of the \texttt{language}
                  field in the database file, the concatenation of the
                  \texttt{editor} and \texttt{translator} fields, and the
                  \texttt{afterword} field},
}




%\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\newcommand\abibname{ext-verbose}
\newcommand\abibstyle{style=\abibname}\usepackage[
    \abibstyle , 
        ]{biblatex}
\newcommand\mynote{biblatex option used: \texttt{\abibstyle}.}
\defbibnote{abibnote}{\mynote}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\newcommand\vpsng{s}
\newcommand\vpspl{}
\newcommand\bstrnotavailable{\texttt{<not available>}}


\newcommand\confirmcsname[4]{%
{\color{blue}\textbackslash \texttt{#1}}: \ifcsdef{#1}{#3 \csname #1\endcsname{#2} #4}{\bstrnotavailable}}

\newcommand\testthecites[2]{%
\textbf{\large Example citations -- \abibname}
\begin{itemize}
%\item \confirmcsname{cite}{#1}{}{}\hfill x   
\item \confirmcsname{textcite}{#1}{as}{say#2,}\hfill x   
%\item \confirmcsname{parencite}{#1}{as noted}{.}\hfill x   
%\item \confirmcsname{supercite}{#1}{text}{}\hfill x 
\item \confirmcsname{footcite}{#1}{a}{}\hfill x 
\item \confirmcsname{footfullcite}{#1}{a}{}\hfill x 
%\item \confirmcsname{citetitle}{#1}{as}{says}\hfill x 
%\item \confirmcsname{citeauthor}{#1}{as}{say#2}\hfill x   
%\item \confirmcsname{posscite}{#1}{in}{landmark work}\hfill x  
%\item \confirmcsname{autocite}{#1}{}{}\hfill x
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\frame[t]{
\frametitle{title}

item to be cited\footnote{xxx}

item to be cited too\footnote{yyy}

\testthecites{cicero}{\vpsng}
}              

\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**

Activating (some) French settings in a non-French context can be done.

French Babel has a `\frenchbsetup{ShowOptions}`, which is very handy.

So, adapting the answer from ([French and English text in one document with a single style of footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66127/french-and-english-text-in-one-document-with-a-single-style-of-footnote)):

Here, footnote numbers in the text are spaced superscripts, and foonote numbers in the footnotes are non-superscripts, and the main language is English.

[image: cites]

[image: options]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{lorenz,
author = {Katharina G Lorenz},
year = {2014},
title = {The Casa del Menandro in Pompeii},
subtitle ={Rhetoric and the Topology of Roman Wall Paintings},
pages={183-210},
editor = {J Elsner and M Meyer},
booktitle = {Art and Rhetoric in Roman Culture},
publisher = {Cambridge},}

@INCOLLECTION{auler:hiller:2011,
 AUTHOR = {Jost Auler AND Petra Hiller},
 TITLE = {Ein Kinderschuh des 19. Jahrhunderts aus Dor\-ma\-gen\--Stür\-zel\-berg, Rhein-Kreis Neuss},
 KEYWORDS = {Schuh, Kind, Dormagen, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 19. Jahrhundert},
 CROSSREF = {radmacher:kronsbein:2011},
 PAGES = {65--73},
 GENDER = {pp},
 SHORTTITLE = {Kinderschuh},
 GENDER = {pp},
}
@COLLECTION{radmacher:kronsbein:2011,
 EDITOR = {Franz-Josef Radmacher AND Stefan Kronsbein},
 TITLE = {Archiv und Erinnerung im Rhein-Kreis Neuss},
 TITLEADDON = {Festschrift für Karl Emsbach},
 FESTSCHRIFT = {Karl Emsbach},
 DATE = {2011},
 PUBLISHER = {Kreisheimatbund},
 SERIES = {Schriftenreihe des Kreisheimatbundes Neuss},
 NUMBER = {18},
 LOCATION = {Neuss},
 LANGUAGE = {german},
 GENDER = {pm},
 }

@book{cicero,
  author       = {Cicero, Marcus Tullius},
  title        = {De natura deorum. {\"U}ber das Wesen der G{\"o}tter},
  date         = 1995,
  editor       = {Blank-Sangmeister, Ursula},
  translator   = {Blank-Sangmeister, Ursula},
  afterword    = {Thraede, Klaus},
  language     = {langlatin and langgerman},
  publisher    = {Reclam},
  location     = {Stuttgart},
  langid       = {german},
  indextitle   = {De natura deorum},
  shorttitle   = {De natura deorum},
  annotation   = {A bilingual edition of Cicero's \emph{De natura deorum}, with
                  a German translation. Note the format of the \texttt{language}
                  field in the database file, the concatenation of the
                  \texttt{editor} and \texttt{translator} fields, and the
                  \texttt{afterword} field},
}




\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\frenchbsetup{ShowOptions,FrenchFootnotes=true,AutoSpaceFootnotes=true,AutoSpacePunctuation=true}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\newcommand\abibname{ext-verbose}
\newcommand\abibstyle{style=\abibname}\usepackage[
    \abibstyle , 
        ]{biblatex}
\newcommand\mynote{biblatex option used: \texttt{\abibstyle}.}
\defbibnote{abibnote}{\mynote}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\newcommand\vpsng{s}
\newcommand\vpspl{}
\newcommand\bstrnotavailable{\texttt{<not available>}}


\newcommand\confirmcsname[4]{%
{\color{blue}\textbackslash \texttt{#1}}: \ifcsdef{#1}{#3 \csname #1\endcsname{#2} #4}{\bstrnotavailable}}

\newcommand\testthecites[2]{%
\textbf{\large Example citations -- \abibname}
\begin{itemize}
%\item \confirmcsname{cite}{#1}{}{}\hfill x   
\item \confirmcsname{textcite}{#1}{as}{say#2,}\hfill x   
%\item \confirmcsname{parencite}{#1}{as noted}{.}\hfill x   
%\item \confirmcsname{supercite}{#1}{text}{}\hfill x 
\item \confirmcsname{footcite}{#1}{a}{}\hfill x 
\item \confirmcsname{footfullcite}{#1}{a}{}\hfill x 
%\item \confirmcsname{citetitle}{#1}{as}{says}\hfill x 
%\item \confirmcsname{citeauthor}{#1}{as}{say#2}\hfill x   
%\item \confirmcsname{posscite}{#1}{in}{landmark work}\hfill x  
%\item \confirmcsname{autocite}{#1}{}{}\hfill x
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\frame[t]{
\frametitle{title}

item to be cited\footnote{xxx}

item to be cited too\footnote{yyy}

\testthecites{cicero}{\vpsng}
}              


\frame[t]{
\frametitle{French Babel settings}
\sffamily\scriptsize
***** List of possible options for babel-french ****
* [Default values between brackets when french is loaded *LAST*]
* ShowOptions [false]
* StandardLayout [false]
* GlobalLayoutFrench [true]
* PartNameFull [true]
* IndentFirst [true]
* ListItemsAsPar [false]
* StandardListSpacing [false]
* StandardItemizeEnv [false]
* StandardEnumerateEnv [false]
* StandardItemLabels [false]
* ItemLabels=\textbackslash textemdash , \textbackslash textbullet , \textbackslash ding{43},... [\textbackslash textendash ]
* ItemLabeli=\textbackslash textemdash , \textbackslash textbullet , \textbackslash ding{43},... [\textbackslash textendash ]
* ItemLabelii=\textbackslash textemdash , \textbackslash textbullet , \textbackslash ding{43},... [\textbackslash textendash ]
* ItemLabeliii=\textbackslash textemdash , \textbackslash textbullet , \textbackslash ding{43},... [\textbackslash textendash ]
* ItemLabeliv=\textbackslash textemdash , \textbackslash textbullet , \textbackslash ding{43},... [\textbackslash textendash ]
* StandardLists [false]
* ListOldLayout [false]
* \textcolor{red}{\textbf{FrenchFootnotes [true]}}
* \textcolor{red}{\textbf{AutoSpaceFootnotes [true]}}
* AutoSpacePunctuation [true]
* ThinColonSpace [false]
* OriginalTypewriter [false]
* UnicodeNoBreakSpaces [false]
* og= <left quote character>, fg= <right quote character>INGuillSpace [false]
* EveryParGuill=open, close, none [open]
* EveryLineGuill=open, close, none [open in LuaTeX, none otherwise]
* InnerGuillSingle [false]
* ThinSpaceInFrenchNumbers [false]
* SmallCapsFigTabCaptions [true]
* CustomiseFigTabCaptions [true]
* OldFigTabCaptions [false]
* FrenchSuperscripts [true]
* LowercaseSuperscripts [true]
* SuppressWarning [false]
* 
* *********************************************
* \textbackslash frenchsetup{ShowOptions} on input line 107.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make the statement in the first sentence even stronger: `biblatex` typesets its footnotes with `\footnote` and does not attempt to change the footnote layout (except by adding a final period at the end of the footnote contents). The other visible change in output (that the OP does not seem to be too concerned about) is that with `biblatex`'s French language module family names are typeset in small caps. This can be turned off as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864 if desired.

Comment: @Cicada thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I agree that the French is easier on the eye, that is why I wanted it for my presentation.

Comment: @Cicada, I do have one question though, with your solution is it possible to combine the biblatex "French" style with the "English" option for babel ?

Comment: @Alain Babel drives the style for the language; Biblatex just follows. What would a French-English style look like? Do you mean non-superscript footnote numbers? And French spacing?

Comment: @Alain - see amended answer.

Comment: @Cicada - excellent, thank you !